# JSONObject cannot be cast to JSONArray, SimpleJSON

Tags: java, json

Have the following code:

```
String s= v.request("engine/?key=", "P4z72NmBa91&method=load");
JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
Object obj = parser.parse(s);
JSONArray arr = (JSONArray)obj;
System.out.println(arr);
```

Which outputs:

```
[
    {"time":"2012-09-10 19:09:08",
     "username":"SomeUsername",
     "times_logged":"1",
      "ip":"33.33.33.33"
     }
]
```

Sorry if the above is not formatted correctly.

Anyway, there are multiple sets of these in `arr`, and when I do `arr.get(0)` it returns the first one, as expected.  What isn't working right is I can't do `arr.get(0).get(1)` or `arr.get(0).get("time")` or anything like that.  I've tried to set it up like this:

```
    for(int i = 0; i < arr.size(); i++) {
        JSONArray p = (JSONArray)arr.get(i);
        System.out.println(p.get(0));
    }
```

, and I get the error mentioned in the title of my question. Although I believe that `arr` isn't a JSONArray, but a JSONObject?  If that is the case, how can I iterate through off things contained in `arr` and get each item?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
 for(int i = 0; i < arr.size(); i++) {
        JsonObject p = (JsonObject)arr.get(i);
        System.out.println(p.get("time").getAsString());
    }
```

Comment: The method getString(String) is undefined for the type JSONObject

Comment: Thanks, I had just found out that was the answer a few seconds before you updated :D